# Regex for extracting string from csv before numbers

Tags: r, regex, csv

I'm very new to the regex world and would like to know how to extract strings using regex from a bunch of file names I've imported to R.  My files follow the general format of:

```
testing1_010000.csv
check3_012000.csv
testing_checking_045880.csv
test_check2_350000.csv
```

And I'd like to extract everything before the 6 numbers.csv part, including the "_" to get something like:

```
testing1_
check3_
testing_checking_
test_check2_
```

If it helps, the pattern I essentially want to remove will always be 6 numbers immediately followed by .csv.

Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the "regex world" !

Comment: If you're always removing 6 numbers followed by ".csv", why not just remove the last 10 characters?

Comment: online regex generators can be very helpful https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways you could go about this. For example, match anything before a string of six digits followed by ".csv". For this one you would want to get the first capturing group.

```
/(.*)\d{6}.csv/
```

https://regex101.com/r/MPH6mE/1/

Or match everything up to the last underscore character. For this one you would want the whole match.

```
.*_
```

https://regex101.com/r/4GFPIA/1

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much!  Ended up keeping it simple and sticking with .*_ which worked perfectly with how I was using this with R's `str_extract` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Files = c("testing1_010000.csv", "check3_012000.csv",
    "testing_checking_045880.csv", "test_check2_350000.csv")
sub("(.*_)[[:digit:]]{6}.*", "\\1", Files)

 
[1] "testing1_"         "check3_"           "testing_checking_"
[4] "test_check2_"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `nchar`:

```
Files = c("testing1_010000.csv", "check3_012000.csv",
          "testing_checking_045880.csv", "test_check2_350000.csv")

substr(Files, 1, nchar(Files)-10)

OR

library(stringr)

str_remove(Files, "\\d{6}.csv")
```

```
[1] "testing1_"         "check3_"           "testing_checking_"
[4] "test_check2_"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `stringr::str_match()`. It will also work for different that six digits.

```r
library(tidyverse)

files <- c("testing1_010000.csv", "check3_012000.csv", "testing_checking_045880.csv", "test_check2_350000.csv")



str_match(files, '(.*_)\\d+\\.csv$')[, 2]
#> [1] "testing1_"         "check3_"           "testing_checking_"
#> [4] "test_check2_"
```

The regex can be interpreted as:
"capture everything before and including an underscore, that is then followed by one or more digits .csv as an ending"

<sup>Created on 2021-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>